# Recognize custom touchDown gesture and make scrollView scrollable Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c

There's a input toolbar appearing at bottom of screen, a UITextView which be contained becomes firstResponser when user wanna input something, and at this moment the input toolbar animates to the top of UIKeyboard.

What I want to do is to make input toolbar go back to the bottom when the tap event begins, so I implement a custom gesture [TouchDownGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/Julyyq/TouchDownGestureRecognizer) adding to a UITableView (list history messages). Then the problem appeared: **The UITableView can't scroll when touchDown**.

So how to recognize custom touchDown gesture and make scrollView scrollable Simultaneously?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is a little difficult to solve the problem by this way, so I do touch down stuff in the `- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method.